# Find an equation of the plane spanned by $v_1$ and $v_2$, find a vector $v_3$ that can be added to produce a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $v_1=(-1,2,3)$ and $v_2=(5,3,-1)$. Find the equation of the plane spanned by $v_1$ and $v_2$. Also find a vector $v_3$ that can be added to the set $\{v_1,v_2\}$ to produce a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$.

I'm stuck on both parts because everywhere I read it says I need a point in addition to these two vectors to find the equation.

For the second part I'm not sure of the method to find a vector to produce a basis, we haven't been told how to do that... I know a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$ would have to have $3$ vectors that span $\mathbb{R}^3$ and must be L.I., so I know that $kv_1 + kv_2 + kv_3 = 0$ must be $k_1=k_2=k_3 = 0$ ...but what is a concrete method to find a third vector $v_3$?

Forgive me if I missed somewhere I could have found this out, I couldn't seem to find the method.

Comment: What about all the pints $p\in\mathbb{R}^3$ that can be written as $$p=tv_1+rv_2$$ for $t,r\in\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: oh so I'm supposed to find a general paramentric equation? I thought I had to "find" something specific by computing. Can you tell me how to find a vector to make it a basis by chance? I have an idea of how one would pass a test but I'm having trouble of finding one to begin with.

Comment: We need a vector $v_3$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that not belong to Span$\{v_1,v_2\}$, we can choose $v_3=(1,0,0)$. And then, to proof that Span$\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}=\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: oh so I should just start picking at random then verifying with determinant. Is there a faster way I could find it using the cross product?

Comment: Yes, $v_1\times v_2$ give you a vector $v_3$ as you need!

Comment: is it guaranteed to result in span{v1,v2,v3} = R3?

Comment: I just now found something that said v1 and v2 can't be parallel. does that mean they can't be a linear combination of eachother? how would you know for sure..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let $\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}$ be a point in Span$\{v_1,v_2\}$, so there are $t,r\in\mathbb{R}$ such that
\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}&=tv_1+rv_2\\
&=t\begin{pmatrix}-1\\2\\3\end{pmatrix}+r\begin{pmatrix}5\\3\\-1\end{pmatrix}\\
&=\begin{pmatrix}-1&5\\2&3\\3&-1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} t \\ r\end{pmatrix}...(1)
\end{align*}
This system can be written as $$\begin{pmatrix}-1&5&|&x\\2&3&|&y\\3&-1&|&z\end{pmatrix}$$
By mean of elementary operations by rows we get $$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&|&4x-5y+5z\\0&1&|&x-y+z\\0&0&|&11x-14y+13z\end{pmatrix}$$
Then, (1) has solutions iff $11x-14y+13z=0$, this is the equation of the plane.

Answer (score 2):

To find a third vector to produce a basis for $\mathbb{R^3}$, take your vectors *v1* and *v2* and row reduce to find out where your pivots are.

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
-1&5\\
2&3\\
3&-1\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$ is row equivalent to:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0\\
0&1\\
0&0\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Because we need a pivot in the third row to produce a basis for $\mathbb{R^3}$, we can add the vector

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0\\
1\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

to produce a basis set.

Answer (score 0):

Consider general equation of the plane $ax+by+cz=d$.

The plane that passes through origin can be expressed as:

$ax+by+cz=0$ and even further, $Ax+By+z=0$.

Then first vector gives $A(-1)+B(2) + 3=0$; and the second $A(5)+B(3)-1=0$.

Solving the above system for A and B gives $A=11/13; B=-14/13$.

Hence the plane is $11x-14y+13z=0\cdot 13=0$.

Note that vector $(11;-14;13)$ is perpendicular to the plane, meaning that we can take it as $v_3$ to span $\mathbb R^3$.

Answer (score 0):

The vectors $w_1,w_2,w_3$ are linearly independent if and only if $\det(w_1,w_2,w_3) \neq 0$. It follows that $(x,y,z)$ is a linear combination of $(-1,2,3)$ and $(5,3,-1)$ if and only if
$$\det \begin{pmatrix} x & -1& 5\\ y & 2 & 3\\ z & 3 & -1\end{pmatrix} = 0.$$
Expanding the left hand side we get

$$(-2 - 9)x - (1-15)y + (-3-10)z = 0 \iff -11x+14y-13z = 0$$
which is the equation of the plane we are looking for. Moreover $(-11,14,-13)$ is not an element of this plane which means that $(-1,2,3),(5,3,-1)$ and $(-11,14,-13)$ are linearly independent (and therefore form a basis).